# What is the number of distinct simple graphs G such that T is a spanning tree of G?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Consider a tree T in which the degree of each vertex is either 1 or 3.
Let n = |V(T)|, where V() is the set of vertices.

**What is the number of distinct simple graphs G such that T is a spanning tree of G?**

So far here's what I've done:

I've shown that n is even. I've shown that T has $\frac n 2 + 1$ leaves.

T is a spanning tree of G => V(T) = V(G)

I'm using a theorem that for any finite set V, there are $2^{
|V|\choose2}$ distinct simple graphs with vertex set V.

Hence there are $2^{n\choose2}$ distinct simlpe graphs.

Then I've used another theorem that for $n\ge2$ there are $n^{n-2}$ distinct trees with n vertices.

Therefore, we have $n^{n-2}$ spanning trees with n vertices.

Hence, total distinct simple graphs = $n^{n-2} . 2^{n\choose2}$

check?

Comment: I think it's easier than that, our graph must contain all the edges of the tree. So we must simply decide which of the remaining $\binom{n}{2}-(n-1)$ edges must lie on the graph.

Comment: before I attempt this method, could you confirm if my final answer is still correct as I used an alternative method?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the original question.

Comment: which specific part?

Comment: when the tree is a star with a center of degree $3$ what is the answer?

Comment: Is the answer for that 6?

Comment: My question is the following: Do you want to count the number of isomorfism classes of graphs on n vertices that have a spanning tree isomorfic to T or do you want to count the number of graphs on the vertex set {1,2,....,n} that hava a spanning tree isomorfic to T. Or do you want to count the number of graphs on the same vertex set a T that contain T as a subgraph? I think those are the three posibilities.

Comment: I believe the last one, contains T as a subgraph that is a spanning tree

Comment: I think for the third option my answer is correct. I also thing that your answer is way too big for any of the three options.

Comment: so $2^{{n\choose2} - n+1}$

Comment: yes, but I'm not sure that's the version that you need to solve, because we aren't using any of the extra conditions we are told the tree satisfies.

Comment: n is even and and each vertex has degree 1 or 3 and G is simple that's the only conditions